# jpod error, where is the FileLocator?

Tags: pdf

I am trying to evaluate the jPod PDF library, the import line:

```
import de.intarsys.tools.locator.FileLocator;
```

says it cannot be resolved. I have jPod.JAR and iscommon.jar, What other JARs do I need to get the FileLocator?

Comment: You need isrt.jar file.

Comment: thank you that worked.  Now I need to resolve the JVMCFRE003 bad major version at runtime:    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=de/intarsys/tools/locator/ILocator, offset=6

Comment: Recent versions of jPod are built with Java 7 and need Java 7 to run.